# Cube rotation about its edge rather than axis

Tags: wpf, 3d, rotation, cube

I am quite new to using Visual Studio and WPF. I have always used Arduino and Processing together but I am now trying to replace Processing with WPF, since it looks more professional. The problem i have in WPF is that i have drawn a cube and i need to rotate it about 2 of its edges rather than the x- and y-axes.

I think that a possible solution would be that when i use RotateTransform3D.Rotation and AxisAngleRotation3D, i can enter sine and cosine values of angles of rotation in the Axis="" part of the code but i don't know how to get the values of rotation from previous rotations. Can anyone help?